# Jupyter lab moves back to subfolder automatically after moving up a folder

Tags: jupyter-lab

When I click on the folder icon to move up a folder in jupyter lab, after a few seconds it changes to the folder and then almost immediately moves back. Sometimes if I do this several times, it will eventually move up a folder and stay there. This has made jupyter lab unusable for me.

I've tried clicking slowly to make sure I'm not double clicking. I've also uninstalled jupyter and reinstalled it, but the issue persists. I don't have any extensions installed but I did use the table of contents extension in the past. I also tried this on a different machine using a different browser (Firefox vs Chrome on my main computer), but I have the same issue on both machines.

My start folder is a network drive, but I've always used it that way and the problem only started in the past few months. Has anyone else encountered this issue and know of a fix?

I'm not using Anaconda, if that's relevant.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have the option "Show Active File in File Browser" checked in? You can find it in the top menu bar in "Settings" menu.

Comment: @krassowski - No, "Show Active File in File Browser" isn't checked. I tried with it checked and unchecked, but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: I can investigate it further but I will need more information. Could you please open a [bug report on JupyterLab GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md) and fill in all the fields in the report template including all details sections, please?

Comment: @krassowski - I opened a bug here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10940